# Qt-vs-addin cannot find the installation of VS 2015

Tags: c++, qt

I installed both VS2005 and VS 2015 on my laptop. Downloaded the Qt 5.5 and qt-vs-addin-1.2.4-opensource .exe. When I tried to install qt-vs-addin after I installed Qt 5.5, an error occur "The installer could not find an installation of Visual200x Please note that Visual C++ Express in not supported", but I am sure there are VS 2015 and VS2005 on my laptop. That confused me a lot. anyone can help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's likely that VS2005 is too old, while VS2015 is too new. Try with VS2008, Qt Addin was able to detect it. Also don't they list the supported versions in their site?

Comment: I use Qt Visual Studio AddIn ver 1.2.3 with VS2012 and VS2013. For some reason I had a bit of headache with ver. 1.2.4 which was glitching too much to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Qt Addin's wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/Visual_Studio_Add-in):

> These instructions refer to Visual Studio 2012. Replace any references to VS2012 with the appropriate file for your VS version (2008, 2010 and 2012 supported).

Neither VS2005 nor VS2015 are supported (as of today, 09/19/2015). VS2005 might be supported by an older version of the addin.

Answer (score 1):

there is an Extension (Tools > Extensions & Updates) called Qt5Package which has the same functionality as qt add-in. After installing it, you have the Qt entry on your main toolbar where you have to specify a version and the path to the directory where you built it. This version will also be associated with the current project via the same menu.